# How to change storage class of object in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I need to change storage class of a s3 object from STANDARD class into STANDARD_IA using s3cmd. Can anybody help me to do this task. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it possible to do that with boto3?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to change the storage class on all objects within a bucket use:

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://<bucket-name>/ s3://<bucket-name>/ --recursive --storage-class <storage_class>
```

> --storage-class (string) The type of storage to use for the object. Valid choices are: STANDARD | REDUCED_REDUNDANCY | STANDARD_IA | ONEZONE_IA | INTELLIGENT_TIERING | GLACIER | DEEP_ARCHIVE. Defaults to 'STANDARD'

Source: [cp @ AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

Comment: does that incur charges?

Comment: @hytromo Changing the storage class of objects in an S3 bucket typically does not incur additional charges. However, you should be aware that the storage class you choose for your objects may affect the pricing of storage and operations performed on those objects.

Comment: So this cp command will be billed as PUT operation for the original storage class of each object?

Answer (score 11):

Using s3cmd:

```
s3cmd cp s3://BUCKET/KEY s3://BUCKET/KEY --storage-class=STANDARD_IA
```

Using AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET/KEY s3://BUCKET/KEY --storage-class STANDARD_IA
```

**WARNING:** If Versioning is on, this does not change the storage class of the object. It creates a new object with the requested storage class (e.g. STANDARD_IA), but keeps the original version in whatever storage class it was uploaded (e.g. STANDARD). You'll be paying for both copies.

[image: Two versions of the object with different storage classes]

Comment: s3cmd: error: no such option: ----storage-class
 error shows when i tried the given command

Comment: @Gugan sorry, I had a typo in my answer, only 2 dashes needed. See my updated answer.

Comment: i have already tried with two dashes, but it shows same error only

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of s3cmd? I'm basically just reading the documentation for you. You can read it yourself here: http://s3tools.org/usage

Comment: You can also use the following to move the copies between storage types  

`s3cmd mv s3://BUCKET/KEY s3://BUCKET/KEY --storage-class=STANDARD_IA`

Comment: I'm going to add here that both "aws s3 mv" and "aws s3 cp" will modify your metadata on the object, so be prepared. However, the web console's Change Class action keeps the metadata intact.

Comment: using CP will consume a lot resources using daily basis, I wonder if will charge extras...

Comment: @WellingtonOliveira this is a really old post. The best way to do this today, if you have so many objects to change that you are worried about the extra API costs, is to use a lifecycle rule instead.