# How to change storage class of object in s3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to change the storage class of an object in S3 from standard to IA
This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132248/how-to-change-storage-class-of-object-in-s3-bucket) thread. But I would like to do it using boto3 and lambda trigger.

thanks

Comment: Could you give us a sense of how many objects your bucket has? If the number is pretty big, you might want to set up a lifecycle policy.

Comment: i have about 100k objects in the bucket

Answer (score 3):

You can use [copy_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) class:

> You can use the CopyObject action to **change the storage class** of an object that is already stored in Amazon S3 using the StorageClass parameter.

For example:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

bucket_name = '<your bucket-name>'
object_key = '<your-object-key>'

r = s3.copy_object(
    CopySource=f"{bucket_name}/{object_key}",
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Key=object_key,
    StorageClass='STANDARD_IA')
    
print(r)
```

Comment: would that incur any cost?

Comment: @NicWanavit If you have 100k object, then lifecycles would be better as jellycsc  wrote. For S3 you [pay](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) for api calls.